# Guest VMs unable to ping each other within a custom host-only network in vmware workstation

Tags: networking, vmware, virtualization

I have created a custom host only network VMNet2 (without dhcp) in VMware workstation and connected my three VMs with this network.

But the problem is: I cannot ping any VM from any other VM. However I can ping the host VMNet2 adapter from the guest.

I checked the `route` in my guest VMs everything is fine there. I tried to take `tcpdump` for the ping and found that arp request for the destination guest did not get response.

Can anyone explain about this?

My VMware worksation is installed on Windows 7 and I used Ubuntu 12.04 as guest VMs. Following are my network configurations:

```
Guest 1 : IP 192.168.91.2 netmask 255.255.255.0
Guest 2 : IP 192.168.91.3 netmask 255.255.255.0   
Guest 1 : IP 192.168.91.4 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Guest can ping Host machine with VMNet2 adapter id 192.168.91.1, but guest VMs cannot ping each other.

Comment: you might want to look into this [link](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1008184)

Comment: The hypervisor can filter the packets on the virtual network. Use (e.g.) `tcpdump` in order to find out whether the packets reach the other VM. If they do then it's (probably) a firewall problem. Otherwise it's the VMware configuration.